Tonconnect does not work for sending transactions through the mobile app
I am trying to add transaction sending via tonconnect/react-ui
Using Tonkeeper as an example
If you connect the wallet through the desktop application, the transaction sending works correctly
If you connect your wallet through the Tonkeeper mobile app, it throws an error when trying to send a transaction
TonComponent.jsx:35 Transaction error: 
Error: Bad request
    at SendTransactionParser.parseAndThrowError (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:4172:11)
    at TonConnect.<anonymous> (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:6244:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:3976:24)
handleClick  @  TonComponent.jsx:35

My component

const TonComponent = observer(({ title }) => {
  const wallet = useTonWallet();
  const [tonConnectUI, setOptions] = useTonConnectUI();
  const { amount } = ModalStore;
  
  const transaction = {
    // validUntil: validUntil,
    messages: [
      {
        address: "UQCXWm9dAZD6bzyiPMLjTLSnfrk0nej38XmnZYVVm2exEmK3",
        amount: '500000', 
        // payload: UserStore.id
      }
    ]    
  }
  console.log('Transaction:', transaction);
  
  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction);
      console.log('Transaction sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Transaction error:', err);
    }
  };
  
  return wallet ? (
    <Button variant={'contained'} color={'success'} onClick={handleClick}>
      {title}
    </Button>
  ) : (
    <TonConnectButton />
  );
});

export default TonComponent;

I am trying add validUntil but is not work
const validUntil = Math.floor(Number(new Date()) / 1000) + 360

What about the commented bits, does anything changes if you uncomment validUntil, for instance?

To send transaction successfully you need to add required property validUntil, for example:
validUntil: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 360,

